# Pass $scope data from controller to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I want to display `$scope.predicate` and `$scope.reverse` values into my view(in the `<p>` tag ). It seems that using `{{ }}` expression is not working.

**app.js:**

```
 var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
 app.controller('TestController', function($scope,$http ){
 var vm = this;
 vm.rezdata = [];
 $http.get("some rest resource...")
      .then(function(response) {
          vm.rezdata =  response.data;
          $scope.predicate = 'username';
          $scope.reverse = true;
      });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <h1>Users table </h1>  
    <table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="TestController as test">
        <p> Sorting predicate {{predicate}}; reverse = {{reverse}} </p>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>
                    Username
                </th>
                ... 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
            <tr ng-repeat="datafinal in test.rezdata" >  
                <td>{{ datafinal.id}} </td>
                <td>{{datafinal.username}} </td>
                ...
            </tr>
        </tbody>        
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't put a <p> element in a <table>, although that's probably not the underlying issue.  You can use <caption> instead if you'd like.

Comment: I think You should resolve it by `$q`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `ng-controller="TestController as test"` on `body` tag.

Also as you are using `controller as` syntax while using controller, so the value inside the controller context (`this`) is accessible on HTML by its alias `test`. `{{test.predicate}}; reverse = {{test.reverse}}` should work.

But technically you shouldn't use both `$scope` & `this` in same controller while using `controller as`, which will again create a confusion. So I'd suggest you to change `$scope` to `vm`.

```
<p>Sorting predicate {{predicate}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</p>
<table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="TestController as test">
   ...  
</table>
```

Comment: Changed p to  <pre> tag and with test prefix.Still not working.

Comment: @Lucas mistake is `invalid html`, so unless you move `p` tag out of table, it will not printout the html.

Comment: @Lucas look at edit...you need to move `ng-controller` on body tag as you need to make controller context available for `p` tag :)

Comment: Done.I moved the controller to a container div.Thank you  Pankaj Parkar.

Comment: @Lucas Glad to know that.. Thanks :)